# iPhone contacts doesn't get sync via iCloud to Mac (iOS 8.1, Yosemite)

Tags: ios, contacts, osx-yosemite

I have my iCloud account setup, Contacts app checked. Everything is set up properly. New contacts on Mac got synced to iPhone. However, new contacts I created on iPhone doesn't appear on Mac. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open Contacts app. In "All Contacts" page (should be already opened as default), on top left, there is a Refresh button. Tap that and contacts on my iPhone got synced and appears on Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you have contacts being added on your phone to a default email on your phone but you don't know it is the default.

Go to contacts and check what emails you have set up. Usually it will default to the first email on the list. If a yahoo email was the first one you have inputed into your phone then likely all contacts are automatically added to that email's contacts.

If this is the case you will have to go to that email online, export the contacts, and then import them into your contacts on your mac.

I made this video which demonstrates the same solution if you don't like reading.

https://youtu.be/I4glpmZbpPA

Comment: The video you linked to is in your name, which suggests spam. To avoid getting your answer flagged as spam, please provide disclosure. For more information, see http://superuser.com/help/promotion

Comment: Is it good now that I included that it is my video?